# MPI why is this simple loop not working?

Tags: c, mpi

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#define BUFFER_SIZE 65536

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
        int int_buff[BUFFER_SIZE];
        char char_buff[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int n, myid;
        int buflen, ntimes;
        double starttime, endtime;

        MPI_Status status;
        MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
        buflen = 2;

        if (myid == 0) {
                int i;
                for (i = 0 ; i++ ; i < 500  ) {
                printf("Lala");
                }
        }
        MPI_Finalize();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am using doing `mpiexec --hostfile hostfile -np 2 ping_pong`. Nothing is printed but when I change the loop top `for(;;)` it works, why is that ?

Comment: If you are still unsure of how to use for loops maybe MPI could wait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expressions in your `for` loop is placed wrong. Syntax of [`for` loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop) is

```
 for(INITIALIZATION; CONDITION; INCREMENT/DECREMENT)
     Statement
```

Change

```
for (i = 0 ; i++ ; i < 500  )
```

to

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 500; i++  )
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code you have:

```
for (i = 0 ; i++ ; i < 500)
```

You've mixed up i++ (what to do on every iteration) and i < 500 (condition for iteration). Try:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 500; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the other answers, your for loop reversed the condition and the increment sections.
Interestingly enough, this is still a valid piece of code.

What your code actually does is check the condition for the first time trying to enter the loop, performs the increment (with the side effect of actually incrementing `i`, but returns the pre-incremented value. The increment section just performs the comparison with 500, and the result is ignored.

Since `i` starts at 0, your loop condition evaluates as false and exits right away